# is it possible to use scp commands under windows environment?

Tags: windows, scp

Is it possible to use "scp" command on how to transfer file from server to server under windows environment? I am connected to a windows 8 server using a remote desktop. now i will connect to a linux server  but the windows environment doesnt support sftp only ftp. I thinking of using scp.

Now that's my problem. I dont know if my tags are correct. correct me if I'm wrong. please guide me. Im just new in server. There is an app that will transfer a file to the windows server, Im planning to transfer it from windows server to linux server.

Comment: There are several different (trivial) solution presented below; however, this sort of question should probably be asked on a different stack site as it's not explicitly related to a programming issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure it is : use pscp from here : http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html
I use it every day as a task on Windows to automate things.

Comment: so this pscp can make my commands automated?

Comment: automated ? yes sure man !

Comment: thanks for this bro. I will search on how to automate the commands. and will integrate it on my app that I'm creating. thanks. :)

Comment: You will be glad with this command ! this soft is a killer !

Comment: isn't the winscp can also do automation?

Comment: Honestly, don't take care about winscp, it's good for ponctual transfert

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42909/discussion-between-vincent-and-user2196728)

Answer (score 5):

I prefer [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php), it has a nice GUI:

> WinSCP is an open source free SFTP client, *SCP client*, FTPS client and FTP client for Windows. Its main function is file transfer between a local and a remote computer.

[PSCP](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) is also an option.

Comment: WinSCP is what i use everydays for one shot transfer. I usually use pscp for automation ;)

Comment: Yes it is nice, but then what ? "PSCP is also an option" PSCP is THE option. WinSCP great for one shot needs...

Comment: I've only ever used winscp for one shot deals and keeping directories synchronized.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using Cygwin to get many of the useful Linux commands like SCP.

See [these instructions for how to setup in windows 7/8](http://www.question-defense.com/2010/01/07/how-to-install-scp-and-ssh-on-windows-7-using-cygwin).

Comment: Cygwin is an overkill for that ! ;)

Comment: True, but I thought it would be good to know it's a possibility -- and it only takes a few minutes to setup.